# vscode extension find all the project the opend

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Im creating a VSCodeExtension, is there a way to know the list of the projects that user open on his workspace ,is there any api or good technique to know that ?

for example if user open two nodejs projects or open java and nodejs project,
I believe that im not the first one that need it but I couldn't find and suitable api or method that can help...any idea

Comment: You need to explain what a "project" is. Do you mean a folder in his workspace or how do you define "project" ?

Comment: @Marc - I mean like nodejs app, or java app...

Comment: And what is a "nodejs app" or "java app" ? A  app can be a folder in a workspace or a app in 3 subfolders of the named workspace...

Comment: @Marc - yes exactly, how can I know such, as it's complicated to calculate as user can any project type like node java go etc .

Comment: Simple, you cant. The user define what a "project" is. As i sayed, a project can be multiple folders in a workspace, a single folder and every variant of it. You simple cant say what is defined as a "project" for example. i fave a "playground" folder in my workspace, is that a project or every folder in it ? You simple cant